# How to do inner reference with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to do something like following code, but it failed.

```
var User = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    phone_number: { type: String, required: true },
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    contacts: [{
        user: { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User' }
    }]
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Is it able to achieve that purpose?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: sorry, finally I found it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I used the wrong way to check it, actually it works.

Following is my test :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'contacts_test');

var User = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    phone_number: { type: String, required: true },
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    contacts: [
        {
            user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
        }
    ]
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);

mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    var user1 = new UserModel({name: 'kos', phone_number: "003"});

    user1.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var user2 = new UserModel({name: 'java', phone_number: "008"});
        user2.contacts = [{user: user1._id}];

        user2.save(function (err) {
            UserModel.findById(user2._id)
                .populate('contacts.user')
                .exec(function (err, user) {
                    if (err) console.error(err.stack || err);
                    console.log('user name: ' + user.name);
                    console.error('contact of first result : ', user.contacts[0].user.name);

                    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function () {
                        mongoose.connection.close();
                    });
                });
        });
    });
});
```